# Adding nonce to run multiple contract transactions with web3 python

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to create an ERC-1155 minter in Python that can mint hundreds (or more) NFTs, so I don't want to wait for each to be successful. How can I add nonce to the contract_instance transact() function? I can't seem to find this in the web3 py docs, or is there a better way to do this? I'm also wondering if I should expect some transactions to fail and maybe have some verification step. I did try with "wait_for_transaction_receipt" between each, but it takes about 10~ seconds for each individual mint which may be too slow, and it seems to randomly fail after about 20-30 mints.

With my current code I'm getting this error after about 20+ mints:
`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}`

Appreciate any help you can offer!

Here's my code:

```
from web3 import Web3
from decouple import config
from eth_account import Account
from eth_account.signers.local import LocalAccount
from web3.auto import w3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware,construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware


infura_url = config('INFURA_URL')
print(infura_url)

private_key=Private_Key

account: LocalAccount = Account.from_key(private_key)

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
w3.middleware_onion.add(construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(account))
print(f"Your hot wallet address is {account.address}")
w3.eth.defaultAccount = 'MYADDRESS'

#added for testnet
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
res = w3.isConnected()


for x in range(200):
    address = 'CONTRACT_ADDRESS'
    abi = 'ABI_HERE'
    contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
    thisvar = contract_instance.functions.symbol().call()
    print(thisvar)

    print(x)
    #generate a random address for simulating a large list of addresses
    mint2acc = Account.create('KEYSMASH FJAFJKLDSKF7JKFDJ 1530')
    print(mint2acc.address)
    thistx = contract_instance.functions.mint(mint2acc.address,1,1).transact()
```

Answer (score 0):

in the transact you can put params like that

```
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(mint2acc.address)
contract_instance.functions.mint(mint2acc.address,1,1).transact({"nonce":nonce})
```